# Ethercat lan9255 hanging after flashing hex with ethercat slave stack

Tags: microchip, ethercat

I have a custom hardware using LAN9255.

I used to website to perform all installations and configurations

https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/ethercat/wiki/create-your-first-ethercat-application

Since i am not able to browse it on twincat so i decided to create project using this reference and flash the hex.

Earlier was not able to compile my project, now. after making few changes in the code, compilation is successful. And have flashed the generated hex file using jlink commander.

But the moment when i try to connect to Twincat master, it hangs.

Does anybody have any idea how this can be fixed.